# Impose vertical displacement in one column in tabular environment

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a simple table with three columns, split (by an \hline) into the first two rows and the last two rows.  Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|c}
a & b & xx \\
c & d & xx \\ \hline
e & f & yy \\
g & h & yy
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The entries in the right-most column represent a comparison of the associated two rows:  thus the xx refers to a comparison of the first two rows and the yy refers to a comparison of the last two rows.  As such, there should be just a *single* entry of xx and a *single* entry of yy.  I would like a single xx to lie vertically *between* the first and second rows (to make it clear it refers to *both* rows), and likewise the yy to lie vertically *between* the third and fourth rows.

Comment: You are looking for `multirow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|c}
a & b & \multirow{2}{*}{xx} \\
c & d & \\ \hline
e & f & \multirow{2}{*}{yy} \\
g & h & 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You folks are *so* helpful.  Thanks so very much!  (accept)